# Series expansion $(1-\cos{x})^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How do i get the series expansion $(1-\cos{x})^{-1} = \frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{x^2}{120}+o(x^4)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the (beginning of the) series expansion of cosine at zero?

Comment: What is your background, and what do you know already?Thanks in advance still.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + O(x^3)$$

and so

$$\frac{1}{1 - \cos x}= \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^6}{6!}} = \frac{2}{x^2} \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{360} + O(x^6))}$$
$$ = \frac{2}{x^2} \left( 1 + \left(\frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{360}\right) + \frac{x^4}{144} + O(x^6) \right) = \frac{2}{x^2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{x^2}{120} + O(x^4) $$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 - \cos x} &= \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^6}{720} + o(x^6)\right)^{-1}\\
& = \frac{2}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{12} + \frac{x^4}{360} + o(x^4)\right)^{-1}\\
& = \frac{2}{x^2}\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{12} - \frac{x^4}{360} + \frac{x^4}{144} + o(x^4)\right)\\
& = \frac{2}{x^2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{x^2}{120} + o(x^2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Can help this: $(1-\cos{x})^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{2\sin^2{\dfrac{x}{2}}}=-\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cot{\dfrac{x}{2}}\right)?$